# Place parentheses around superscript citations

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

To meet a journal's requirements I'd like to tweak my current bibliography in a REVTeX4.1 document to:

1. Put parentheses around my (superscripted) citations so they read `(1)`, `(4)`, and `(2,3,5)` rather than `1`, `4`, and `2,3,5`.
2. Put parentheses around each numbered reference in the bibliography so they all read similar to `(12)` rather than `12`. If possible, the bibliography list should be non-superscript while the in-text citations are superscript (not my rules... journal's request).

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,       %   A4 paper, two columns
  nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,       %       
  aps,prb,citeautoscript, 10pt,         %   The prb style of RevTex uses superscript cross-references for citations
  eqsecnum,notitlepage,showkeys]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{hyperref}   % Hyperref likes to be the last package included but putting it last breaks figure references!
\begin{document}
The manuscript elements have been formatted for you with LaTeX. 
References can be included such as \cite{R2006} or \cite{R2009}.
Multiple references are also handled \cite{R2007, R2002,CDCgirlGrowthCharts}.
\bibliographystyle{PAPER_IJAE_BIBTEX_plain}
\bibliography{PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\end{document}
```

With `PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY.bib` containing:

```
@Article{R2007,
   Author="Another, J.  and van Alphabet, B.  and Master, M. A. ",
   Title="{{A}utomatic data is nice}",
   Journal="Med Image",
   Year="2007",
   Volume="11",
   Number="1",
   Pages="35--46",
   Month="Feb"
}
@mastersthesis{R2009,
    author    = "Matthew W. Author",
    title     = "Paper title here",
    school    = "University of Virginia",
    type     = "Master's thesis",
    address  = "",
    year      = "2007",
    month    = "",
    note     = "",
}
@online{CDCgirlGrowthCharts,
  author = {{National Center for Health Statistics}},
  title = {{CDC} Clinical Growth Charts},
  year = 2000,
  url = {http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/clinical_charts.htm},
  urldate = {30/09/2010}
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/clinical_charts.htm}} 
}
@article{R2006,
   author = {Rabbit, Peter F  and Brown, J Charlie and Duck, Donald R},
   title = {Factors of growth},
   journal = {Journal of Surgery},
   volume = {41},
   number = {11},
   pages = {1854-1858},
   year = {2006}
}
@inproceedings{R2002,
   author = {Kane, M. and Freed, Y.},
   title = {Development for safety ({THUMS})},
   booktitle = {Proceedings of conference},
   year = {2002}
}
```

And my `PAPER_IJAE_BIBTEX_plain.bst` is really just a copy of `plain.bst` with a little tweak for formatting names - nothing that would affect the numbering ([link to file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnafofiypm6c8aq/PAPER_IJAE_BIBTEX_plain.bst)). I'm happy to make further changes to the .bst file, I just can't seem to narrow down the bit that affects what I'm trying to change. Any help appreciated.

[image: Showing un-parenthesised cites-bibs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by redefining `\NAT@biblabelnum` and `\NAT@citesuper` (`revtex4-1` internally uses `natbib`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,
  nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,  
  aps,prb,citeautoscript, 10pt,
  eqsecnum,notitlepage,showkeys]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{filecontents}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{filecontents*}{PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY.bib}
@Article{R2007,
   Author="Another, J.  and van Alphabet, B.  and Master, M. A. ",
   Title="{{A}utomatic data is nice}",
   Journal="Med Image",
   Year="2007",
   Volume="11",
   Number="1",
   Pages="35--46",
   Month="Feb"
}
@mastersthesis{R2009,
    author    = "Matthew W. Author",
    title     = "Paper title here",
    school    = "University of Virginia",
    type     = "Master's thesis",
    address  = "",
    year      = "2007",
    month    = "",
    note     = "",
}
@online{CDCgirlGrowthCharts,
  author = {{National Center for Health Statistics}},
  title = {{CDC} Clinical Growth Charts},
  year = 2000,
  url = {http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/clinical_charts.htm},
  urldate = {30/09/2010}
}
@article{R2006,
   author = {Rabbit, Peter F  and Brown, J Charlie and Duck, Donald R},
   title = {Factors of growth},
   journal = {Journal of Surgery},
   volume = {41},
   number = {11},
   pages = {1854-1858},
   year = {2006}
}
@inproceedings{R2002,
   author = {Kane, M. and Freed, Y.},
   title = {Development for safety ({THUMS})},
   booktitle = {Proceedings of conference},
   year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@biblabelnum[1]{\textsuperscript{(#1)}}
\renewcommand\NAT@citesuper[3]{\ifNAT@swa
\unskip\hspace{1\p@}\textsuperscript{(#1)}%
   \if\relax#3\relax\else\ (#3)\fi\else (#1)\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The manuscript elements have been formatted for you with LaTeX. 
References can be included such as \citealp{R2006} or \citep{R2009}.
Multiple references are also handled \cite{R2007, R2002,CDCgirlGrowthCharts}.
\bibliographystyle{PAPER_IJAE_BIBTEX_plain}
\bibliography{PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that worked perfectly for the in-text citations, but my bibliography still doesn't become parenthesised. I get the same result with/without the line: `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textsuperscript{(#1)}}`  I'm using TeXworks and compiling pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex. I've tried compiling just BibTex first as I've noticed changes in the bibliography need 2 compiles to make it through, but no luck yet. Can you help troubleshoot this?

Comment: @sven Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah... got it - just a missing "NAT". Thanks muchly.