# Parentheses around superscript citations in article

Tags: bibtex

I need to change the custom format of bibliography citations to fulfil the requirements of a Conference. In this case, I am using an `article` document with `unsrt` bibliography style. The citations should have the aspect in the caption below (superscript citations between parenthesis):

[image]

Besides that, I need the bibliography to be in the format you can see below:

[image]

I have tried the solution proposed in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160679/place-parentheses-around-superscript-citations) but it does not work for `article` document type. I have tried the code below, but parenthesis are not introduced. Moreover, I do not know how to change the format of the bibliography to adjust it to the requirements.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}

\begin{document}

The reference point\cite{Camci2009} in the text\cite{Ben-Daya2009} should be formatted thus\cite{Berdinyazov2009}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AN alternative is to use `natbib` with the option `super` and `round` instead of `cite`. i.e., `\usepacakge[round,super]{natbib}` and replace `unset` with `unsrtnat`.

Comment: Thanks @Guido, now the citing works properly. What about the format for the bibliography?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative is to use `natbib` instead of `cite`, and the options `super` and `round`.

```
\usepackage[round,super]{natbib}
```

and replace `unsrt` with `unsrtnat`.

The typeset  of the numbers in the bibliography is controlled by `\@biblabel`. Here is a possible way to redefine it.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```