# ConTeXt: Superscript for Citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, context, superscripts

## Background

I would like to cite bibliography references using superscript.

## Example

The setup code so far:

```
\setupbibtex[database=sources]
\setuppublications[
  refcommand=num,
  numbering=yes
]

\setupcite[num][
  left=\empty,
  right=\empty,
]
```

A bibliography entry in `sources.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{kattamuri@debate,
 author = {Kattamuri, Kishore and Silaghi, Marius and Kaner, Cem and Stansifer, Ryan and Zanker, Markus},
 title = {Supporting Debates over Citizen Initiatives},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2005 National Conference on Digital Government Research},
 series = {dg.o '05},
 year = {2005},
 location = {Atlanta, Georgia},
 pages = {279--280},
 numpages = {2},
 url = {https://repository.lib.fit.edu/bitstream/handle/11141/150/cs-2005-03.pdf},
 acmid = {1065321},
 publisher = {Digital Government Society of North America},
}
```

Example document:

```
\starttext
  Citation.\cite[kattamuri@debate]
\stoptext
```

## Problem

There does not appear to be a way to make the [citation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupcite) number superscript. I tried:

```
\setupcite[num][
  left=\empty,
  right=\empty,
  textstyle=\textsuperscript,
]
```

I looked in `bibl-bib.mkiv` and `bibl-tra.mkiv` but could not see how to hook into the citation macros. I spotted `\bibtexnumref` and think it might be useful:

```
\def\bibtexnumref[#1]%
  {\dontleavehmode
   \begingroup
   \bibtexcitationparameter\v!left
   \penalty\plustenthousand
   \ctxlua{bibtex.hacks.resolve("","\number\bibtexblock","#1")}%
   \bibtexcitationparameter\v!right
   \endgroup}
```

## Question

How can ConTeXt produce superscript citation numbers?

## Related

Related LaTeX questions:

- [Biblatex \textcite using a superscript reference number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114833/biblatex-textcite-using-a-superscript-reference-number)
- [Parentheses around superscript citations in article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166613/parentheses-around-superscript-citations-in-article)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mailing list (courtesy of Wolfgang Schuster):

```
% Superscript citation cross-references.
\setupcite[num][
  left=\raisebox{1ex}\hbox\bgroup\tfxx,
  right=\egroup,
]
```